# Java Composite Design Pattern using LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, design-patterns, jaxb, set, composite

My goal is to create an object using the Composite Design Pattern that can be marshaled into XML using JAXB. In addition, in my case, it seems desirable for the composite component to use a Set (e.g., LinkedHashSet) to ensure that no duplicate elements are stored. However, I can only find examples of the Composite Design Pattern that use ArrayList (see below).

https://dzone.com/articles/composite-design-pattern-java-0

http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/10/composite-design-pattern-tutorial/

Is there a conceptual reason why it would not be possible, or desirable, to use a LinkedHashSet in a Composite Design Pattern. Otherwise, can someone explain how to implement the Composite Design Pattern using a LinkedHashSet? I assume this would require using an Iterator on the LinkedHashSet, but I have not been able to figure out a way to provide the get(int i) functionality of ArrayList with .next() functionality of the LinkedHashSet.

Comment: You can get the i-th element from an iterator by creating it and calling `next()` `i` times. But you might find it easier just to use `!contains` and `add` on a `List` (or add things to the set, and then copy into the list).

Comment: Idea behind Composite class is to be container for child's (tree), therefore methods add, remove, getChild are implemented. Container for the child's can be Java collection or any other container, so answer is yes it is possible to use LinkedHashSet. Another example of the Composite: http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Composite/.

Comment: Just playing devil's advocate: No duplicate elements (set) is not an assumption made in the original design pattern as far as I can tell. Surely there's an example that would have (logically) duplicate elements, but perhaps not in your application.

Comment: The intent of the pattern Composite is to treat a group of objects similar to treating and individual object. This is a generic pattern and is not directly tied to what kind of collection object you are working with. So ArrayList or LinkedHashSet does not matter ....